# distinguish, include only keyword in R

Tags: r, dplyr

how to make this system in R ?

```
connected_elements <- "science"
containing_elements<-c("sci","ence","wds","scw")
```

Only words made with the letter "s","c","i",,"e","n" are considered OK.
"sci"=OK
"ence"=OK

I would cut it down to one word "substr" and use "match".
This method is not pretty because it uses many "FOR".
I'd love to hear other other ideas.

Comment: Is "sss" OK or not? i.e. are you counting multiplicity of each letter?

Comment: sss is OK. and I want to use "connected_elements".  and I cannot write it explicitly "[^scien]" because keyword may be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to match any character which is not "s", "c", "i" "e" or "n".

```
grepl('[^scien]', containing_elements)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

You can use `ifelse` to assign "ok", "Not ok" :

```
ifelse(grepl('[^scien]', containing_elements), 'Not Ok', 'Ok')
#[1] "Ok"     "Ok"     "Not Ok" "Not Ok"
```

Or without `ifelse` :

```
c('Ok', 'Not ok')[grepl('[^scien]', containing_elements) + 1]
```

Comment: This will pass "sss" i.e. it disregards multiplicity of each letter.

Comment: `grepl('[^scien]', 'sss')` returns `FALSE` meaning "Ok".  I think this is what OP wants since it is only made of letters "s", "c", "i" "e" or "n" ?

Comment: @smci `ence` is considered OK by OP where 'e' is repeated twice so I don't see why 'sss' would be any different.

Comment: ```
connected_elements <- "science"
containing_elements<-c("sci",#ok
                       "ence",#ok
                       "wds",
                       "scw",
                       "sss",#ok
                       "gorl",
                       "nece",#ok
                       "science"#ok
                       )

result <- grepl(paste0('[^',connected_elements,']'), containing_elements)
sum(result==FALSE)
```

output is [5]
that is true answer and simple code!
I haven't been able to find the error, but I think it's a very beautiful code.

Answer (score 1):

We could extract all the characters from the 'connected_elements' into a `list`, check whether the `lengths` of the `list` is equal to the number of characters of 'containing_elements'

```
library(stringr)
c("NotOk", "OK")[(lengths(str_extract_all(containing_elements, 
     str_c("[", connected_elements, "]"))) == nchar(containing_elements)) + 1]
#[1] "OK"    "OK"    "NotOk" "NotOk"
```

---

Or using `str_detect`

```
c("OK", "NotOK")[str_detect(containing_elements, '[^scien]') + 1]
#[1] "OK"    "OK"    "NotOK" "NotOK"
```

---

Or using `grep` and `%in%`

```
containing_elements %in% grep('[^scien]', containing_elements, value = TRUE)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

---

Or using `nzchar` and `gsub`

```
nzchar(gsub(paste0("[", connected_elements, "]"), "", containing_elements))
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: very simple code ! thank you. 
I didn't know "str_c" and "str_detect" until now.
I couldn't have done it without you.

Comment: downvoted? I push "it useful" Δ . Did I press something wrong button ?

Comment: and I'm grateful.

Comment: I'm sorry to make you uncomfortable.
Anyway, thank you for your help.
and I got a -2 too.

Comment: @h-y-jp It didn't make me uncomfortable.  It's only because you commented that it is helpful, I noticed the downvote